# How to redirect to another page after login in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors

To describe my problem: There's a react page where user fills email, .. and sends it to the express BE using Axios.post - that part works. But then I want user to be redirected to registration page (/registration) after wrong login. I used res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/registration") but it throws the same error over and over again.

#### Error

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:3000' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

#### user.js file

```
 //Authenticate user
    router.post("/auth", async (req, res) => {

        const pass = req.body.pass
        const email = req.body.email

        //Same as SELECT command
        await User.findOne({
            where: {
                email: email
            } 
        }).then(function (user) {
            if(!user) {
                res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/registration")
            } else {
                bcrypt.compare(pass, user.pass, function (err, result) {
                    if (result == true) {
                        console.log("Logged in")
                        res.send({
                            token: "123123"
                        })
                    } else {
                        res.redirect('/')
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
```

#### index.js file

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
const db = require('./models/index')

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(express.json())

app.use(cors())

db.sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
    console.log("Drop and re-sync db.");
  });

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    //res.json({message: "WELCOME"})
    res.redirect("http://localhost:3000/")
})


require("./routes/user")(app)
require("./routes/category")(app)
require("./routes/product")(app)

app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("running on port 3001")
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

```
window.location.replace("some location")
```

or

```
window.location = "some location"
```

Answer (score 0):

When the login fails redirect using `this.props.history.push('/registration')` in a class based component in React.

Edit:
If you are using a function based component then

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
let history = useHistory();
```

redirect using `history.push('/registration')`

Comment: Problem is that I use function based component for Login page because I work with useState.